# PayPal MPL initialization issue

Tags: ios, paypal

I have had MPL integrated into an IOS, Getting a PayPal error saying “System unavailable. Please try again later".

Any one know why this is happening?

[image: screenshot of error is here]

Comment: Hi I am facing same problem. Did you solve this issue. PLEASE help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feb 1st, 2016. Seem PayPal update from their side and it's work again.